# How do I convert <td> & <tr> into rows and columns in Beautiful Soup 4?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to pull data from https://www.cars.com/research/ford-fusion-2020/specs/407870/ . I have managed to extract the html data from the "Specifications" tables but I am unable to convert it back into a table for use.

This is what my code currently looks like. All it does is pull all the tables in the desired class. Now I need to convert that html back into a usable table. I have tried to stack find_all commands to sort through the html and pull out all the instances of  and  , but I can't seem to stack the commands because more than 1 element is present.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests


headers = {'User Agent' : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"}
url = 'https://www.cars.com/research/ford-fusion-2020/specs/407870/'

response= requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup= BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html5lib')

tables= soup.find_all(attrs= {'class': "specs-table"})

print (tables)
```

Comment: Question needs some more details about what is expected - e.g. What is `a table for use`?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice to scrape tables is using [`pandas.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) what uses `BeautifulSoup` under the hood. This will give you a `dataframe` to manipulate and export to your needs.

##### Example

```
import pandas as pd
pd.concat(pd.read_html('https://www.cars.com/research/ford-fusion-2020/specs/407870/', attrs= {'class': "specs-table"}), ignore_index=True)
```

##### Output

|  | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | EPA Classification | Midsize Cars |
| 1 | Rear Wheel Material | Aluminum |
| 2 | Front Wheel Material | Aluminum |
| 3 | Spare Wheel Size | N/A in |
| 4 | Rear Wheel Size | 18 X 8 in |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 193 | Tire Specific Low Tire Pressure Warning | Standard |
| 194 | Outboard Front Lap And Shoulder Safety Belts -inc: Rear Center 3 Point, Height Adjusters and Pretensioners | Standard |
| 195 | Side Impact Beams | Standard |
| 196 | Airbag Occupancy Sensor | Standard |
| 197 | Rear Child Safety Locks | Standard |